# Column cannot have NULL value JAVA Server Side

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mysql-workbench

I am new to java Client/Server coding. 
I am implementing a REST Service. My Database has a table Customer (FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, Address)
I am trying to send an ajax call from client side to POST method of this rest class.

However, the Database is throwing NULL Exception and gives me the error : Column 'Email' cannot be null

This is what I am doing in the post method:

```
@Path("customer")
public class CustomerREST {
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addCustomer(@FormParam("FirstName") String fname, @FormParam("LastName") String lname, @FormParam("Phone") String phone, @FormParam("Email") String email, @FormParam("Address") String address)
{
//  , @FormParam("uname") String uname, @FormParam("password") String pwd
    List<Login> L= DataAccessUtil.getAll(Login.class);

    Integer size = L.size();
    Login newLogin = new Login();
    newLogin = L.get(size-1);

    Customer newCustomer = new Customer();

    newCustomer.setAddress("123");
    newCustomer.setEmail("abc");
    newCustomer.setFirstName("abc");
    newCustomer.setLastName("abc");
    newCustomer.setPhone("abc");
    newCustomer.setLogin(newLogin);

    DataAccessUtil.save(newCustomer);

    try {
        return Response.created(new URI("/"+newCustomer.getCustomerId())).build();
    } catch (URISyntaxException exp) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exp).build();
    }
}
}
```

Now, I know that I am sending in some values but the server again throws a NULL Exception.

This is the Stack Trace:

```
Hibernate: insert into customer (Address, Email, FirstName, LastName, Phone,   
idcustomer) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Jan 07, 2014 10:03:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
Jan 07, 2014 10:03:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Column 'Email' cannot be null
Jan 07, 2014 10:03:12 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse                                                  mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP  container
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'Email' cannot be null
at     org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at     org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3028)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3469)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
at mypackage.DataAccessUtil.save(DataAccessUtil.java:13)
at serverside.CustomerREST.addCustomer(CustomerREST.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Email'   cannot be null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
... 52 more
```

Comment: @Funtik I have added the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a value as `null` into a field that does not allow `null` values. The column in question is the `Email` column.  Empty string is not the same as null, so you could just make it that if you need to insert with no value. Since you appear to be setting it in the code, it would most likely point to either a problem in the Hibernate config or something in your HQL/SQL, if you are doing the insert manually.  You would have to share more of your code to really be able to tell, though.

Comment: First it was pointing it to "Address" column. I removed the NotNULL constraint from the Address column, then it started pointing to the Email Column. I am sure that there is something wrong with this particular piece of code.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine.  You create a new customer, populate the email, then save it using your util class.  There isn't much to mess up there.  I suspect your problem is either in your Entity/Domain object or, if you are inserting manually (don't think you are, but hey, never know) it might be there.